# Android adb shell delete SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, shell, adb

I need to delete an SQLite database and in order to do so , i need to access adb shell.

i'm on windows 7 and i have my sdk installed on:

```
C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Android
```

i have opened the cmd and typed adb shell but with no success here is my output :

```
C:\Users\Omar>adb shell
'adb' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

c:\>adb shell
'adb' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
```

"unknown command"

Do i need to do something before calling the adb from my windows cmd ? like creating a classpath ?

Thanks a lot in advance ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add `C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools` to your `PATH` environment variable, or fully-qualify the path to the command you want to run:

```
C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools\adb shell
```

Comment: Can you please help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610016/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-while-fetching-the-date-from-db-and-p

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a single line command like this:

```
adb shell "run-as your.package.name rm /data/data/your.package.name/databases/YourDBFileName.db"
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot it worked with :

```
C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools\adb shell
```

After that i did

```
cd /data/data/(my application package, com...etc)/Databases
```

and

```
rm (mydatabase)
```